# QGraphicsItem disappearing from scene on group remove

Tags: pyqt5, qt5

I'm facing an issue with QGraphicsItem and QGraphicsItemGroup. I can add to group and move the group around but when i try to remove the item from group it get's deleted. I can't find the object in the scene at all.
Same issue if i use a standard class (QGraphicsRectItem)

What is the correct way to remove an item from group while keeping it on the scene.
Code is below:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt,QRect
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QGraphicsView, QGraphicsScene, QGraphicsItem,QApplication, QGraphicsItemGroup, QGraphicsEllipseItem,QPushButton , QVBoxLayout

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets



class Rectangle(QtWidgets.QGraphicsItem):
    def __init__(self,rect):
        super(Rectangle, self).__init__(parent=None)
        self.rect = QtCore.QRectF(rect[0], rect[1], rect[2], rect[3])
        self.setFlag(QtWidgets.QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable)
        self.setFlag(QtWidgets.QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable)
        self.setFlag(QtWidgets.QGraphicsItem.ItemSendsGeometryChanges)
    def boundingRect(self):
        return self.rect

    def paint(self, painter, option, widget=None):
        painter.save()
        painter.setRenderHints(
            QtGui.QPainter.Antialiasing
            | QtGui.QPainter.TextAntialiasing
            | QtGui.QPainter.SmoothPixmapTransform
            | QtGui.QPainter.HighQualityAntialiasing,
            True,
        )
        painter.drawEllipse(self.rect)
        painter.restore()

class Group(QGraphicsItemGroup):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Group, self).__init__()
        self.setFlag(QGraphicsItemGroup.ItemIsMovable)

    def boundingRect(self):
        #if self.childItems():
        #    return self.childrenBoundingRect()
        return QtCore.QRectF(200,200,20,20)

    def paint(self,
              painter: QtGui.QPainter,
              option: QtWidgets.QStyleOptionGraphicsItem,
              widget: QtWidgets.QWidget = None):
        painter.setPen(QtGui.QPen(QtCore.Qt.NoPen))
        painter.setBrush(QtGui.QBrush(QColor(0, 0, 255, 127)))
        painter.drawRect(self.boundingRect())

class MyView(QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.scene = QGraphicsScene()
        self.setScene(self.scene)
        self.setWindowTitle('Test')
        self.setSceneRect(0, 0, 450, 450)
        #add items
        nodeItem = Rectangle([20,200,20,20])
        self.scene.addItem(nodeItem)
        nodeItem2 = Rectangle([40,300,20,20])
        self.scene.addItem(nodeItem2)
        #rect_item = QtWidgets.QGraphicsRectItem(QtCore.QRectF(0, 0, 100, 100))
        #rect_item.setFlag(QtWidgets.QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable, True)
        #self.scene.addItem(rect_item)
        #add buttons
        self.b1 = QPushButton("ungroup")
        self.b1.clicked.connect(self.ungroup)
        self.b1.setGeometry(QRect(10,10,100,100))
        self.b2 = QPushButton("group")
        self.b2.clicked.connect(self.cgroup)
        self.b2.setGeometry(QRect(150,10,100,100))

        self.b3 = QPushButton("print obj")
        self.b3.clicked.connect(self.printobj)
        self.b3.setGeometry(QRect(250,10,100,100))

        self.scene.addWidget(self.b1)
        self.scene.addWidget(self.b2)
        self.scene.addWidget(self.b3)

    def printobj(self):
        for item in self.scene.items():
            print(item)

    def ungroup(self):
        for item in self.group.childItems():
            self.group.removeFromGroup(item)
            print(f'item {item} removed from group {self.group}')
        self.scene.destroyItemGroup(self.group)
        #self.scene.update()


    def cgroup(self):
        self.group = Group()
        self.scene.addItem(self.group)
        for n in self.scene.items():
            if isinstance(n,Rectangle):
                print('n')
                n.setParentItem(self.group)
        #self.scene.update()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])
    f = MyView()
    f.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: i can solve this by setting **self**.nodeItem = Rectangle([20,200,20,20]) and **self**.nodeItem2 = Rectangle([40,300,20,20]) but my app requires the nodeItem to be added dynamic so i can't do self.x for each. Curious why self.nodeItem works but without doesn't. Believe is due to my Rectangle class not having any parent and when it's remove from parent there is no way to add it to the screen. Should i re-add it with self.scene.addItem(nodeItem) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that cycling through the items creates a python wrapper for them, and being it a local reference, it gets automatically garbage collected when the function returns.

The python wrapper *tries* to check the ownership of the graphics item, but removing an item from the group doesn't automatically retransfer the ownership to the scene as it would happen by doing `addItem()`. The result is that the local reference to the items is removed, the garbage collection calls the destructors for the items, and they get deleted from the scene.

Keeping a persistent reference to the removed items could solve the problem:

```
    def ungroup(self):
        self.items = []
        for item in self.group.childItems():
            self.group.removeFromGroup(item)
            self.items.append(item)
```

But consider that if the list is deleted or cleared, those items will be deleted as well, unless they are reparented.

Alternatively, you can explicitly remove the items from the scene and add them again (you should not add an item to the same scene):

```
    def ungroup(self):
        for item in self.group.childItems():
            self.group.removeFromGroup(item)
            self.scene.removeItem(item)
            self.scene.addItem(item)
```

But, since you're going to destroy the group anyway, the solution is to only remove (and properly *delete*) the other items, and destroy the group, so that the remaining item will be transferred back to the scene:

```
    def ungroup(self):
        for item in self.group.childItems():
            if not isinstance(item, Rectangle):
                self.group.removeFromGroup(item)
                del item
        self.scene.destroyItemGroup(self.group)
```

<sup>Notes: 1. if you want to draw an ellipse, just use QGraphicsEllipseItem, so you don't need to override `paint`; 2. the `ItemIsSelectable` flag can cause recursive movements when the item is part of a group;</sup>

Comment: many thanks for the explanation. works as expected now.